# SQL group by и нахождение максимального элемента

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 3 таблицы: Товары (ид/название/цена), Категории (ид/название) и и таблица реализующая связь многие ко многим (ид/идТовара/идКатегории)

Подскажите пожалуйста как написать правильный sql запрос который бы выводил:
название категории, название товара у которого максимальная цена в этой категории, цена этого товара.

Найти максимальную цену для категории и связать потом по цене с товаром не предлагать)) ищу более правильное и красивое решение

Comment: Какую СУБД используете?

Comment: Нумерующий CTE в разрезе категорий с сортировкой по цене, возврат первых записей.

Comment: использую ms sql, но запрос (по идее) не должен зависить от субд и строиться на чистом sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку с CTE, решил эту задачу так:

```
    With CTE As (select  Row_Number() Over(Partition by KategoriyaId Order By price desc) As Row_Num, 
    t.id, t.price, t.name, s.KategoriyaId from tovar as t 
    left join Svyaz as s on s.TovarId = t.Id)
    Select KategoriyaId, price, name From CTE Where ROW_NUM = 1
```

*Update.* Вариант без СТЕ

```
select KategoriyaId, name, price from (
select Row_Number() Over(Partition by KategoriyaId Order By price desc) As Row_Num, 
    t.id, t.price, t.name, s.KategoriyaId from tovar as t 
    left join Svyaz as s on s.TovarId = t.Id
    where KategoriyaId is not null) as t1
where Row_Num = 1
```